# measuring 4.5V with a 4.096V adc

Tags: sensor, adc, voltage-reference

I would like to measure an analog signal from a pressure sensor.
I have an adc with a reference voltage of 4.096V and the maximum output of the sensor is 4.5V what will happen when there is 4.5V on the adc?
Will it break or will it give a maximum output value?

Comment: Maximum output value.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: Potentially both.

Comment: A cheap solution is a divider network then multiply the ADC by this network resistances ratio

Comment: Please edit your post and add links to the datasheets for: your ADC, your sensor.  Without those, it's not possible to write a worthwhile answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the top 9% of the sensor range you can just connect it directly (if the wires are external you may wish to add protection or low pass filtering for noise, and you may wish to add an anti-aliasing filter but that's outside the scope of this question).

If the input exceeds the Vref the **ADC will just read 0x3FF** (\$2^{10}-1\$ = 1023 base 10)- it will saturate at the maximum reading. So you won't be able to tell if the input is 4.097V or 4.500V, and you should indicate a potential error under those conditions.

This is the easiest and best way if you don't need to use the entire sensor range. There is no inaccuracy added, nor any decrease in resolution. So long as your sensor output does not exceed AVcc there will be no bad side effects.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your ADC. For most of the ADCs this shouldn't be a problem, but it's not the best practice.
Better: Add a voltage divider and to lower the resulting voltage. If you just want to cut off an offset, use a diode.

Comment: I use the internal adc of a atmega 2560

Comment: [Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf) Page 365 > If you use a single ended ADC the analog pin input voltage should not exceed \$V_{REF}\$. And the \$V_{REF}\$ should be between 1V and VCC+0.3. So just adapt your reference voltage and you'll be fine.

Comment: oke thank you the problem is that the other pins use the 4.096 reference. whats then a better way to cut it of 4V diode? or a opamp with a 1x gain and a v+ of 4v?

Comment: why not rescaling with voltage divider? An opamp has the same problems with to high input voltage as the ADC has. A diode is not linear, but the easiest.

Comment: i rather don't lose the accuracy of the pressure sensor and if you add a voltage divider or you have to divide it by 2 or you won't get nice values the output is 0-30psi 0.5V-4.5V

Comment: Don't care about _nice values_, you have a ATmega which can calculate whatever you want

Comment: You absolutely **don't** have to divide it by 2.

Comment: For example you can use a resistor ratio of 7/8. Thus makes 0.5V to 0.44V and  4.5V to 3.94V. So your new output voltage range is 0.44V...3.94V

Comment: i have now used a 9/10 so i have a maximum of 4.05V thank you

Comment: Use a potential divider but definitely not a diode. Rather pointlessly introduces an inaccuracy from diode to diode deviations. Use a potential divider and all that goes away.

Comment: @dylan: Consider using low tolerance resitors <=1% depending on what accuracy you require.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it break or will it give a maximum output value?

it will depend on the adc. most adcs will give max value. others can produce readings beyond Vref.